# Cannot access function from perl module without using folder containing module identifier

Tags: perl, dbi

I have a `perl` module named `Mysql_Routines` that contains various functions I use for manipulating `mysql` data with `DBI`. I export these functions as follows:

```
package Mysql_Routines;

use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(connect_to insert_row get_rows);
```

These are accessed from other scripts and modules using the following code:

```
use my_modules::Mysql_Routines qw (connect_to insert_row get_rows);
```

This would all appear to be standard practice, as documented on [Perl Maven](http://perlmaven.com/how-to-create-a-perl-module-for-code-reuse). However, I can only then call these functions by using the module identifier or I get an error that it's an undefined subroutine. For example:

```
my $dbh = Mysql_Routines::connect_to('./config/mysql-local.conf');
```

works.

```
my $dbh = connect_to('./config/mysql-local.conf');
```

throws the following error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::connect_to called
```

It's obviously not a huge issue, although I'd like to understand why this is happening, as I appear to have followed the correct guidelines for creating modules containing functions.

---

Please see my solution below. The package declaration should have included the top directory. Silly mistake.

Comment: Please post the exact error string.

Comment: Please show your full module declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that the problem is that in the package declaration of the module I didn't include the top directory.

Changing `package Mysql_Routines` to `package my_modules::Mysql_Routines` solves the problem. With this solution the library search path does not need to be updated as was suggested as an alternative.

Comment: I should also change the naming of the directory containing the module to `My_modules`

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confused about the name of your module. Is it "Mysql_Routines" or "my_modules::Mysql_Routines"? I suspect that you want it to be called "Mysql_Routines", in which case your `use my_modules::Mysql_Routines` is rather unusual. Wny wouldn't you just have `use Mysql_Routines`?

I guess the answer is that your module lives in a directory called "my_modules". In which case, the correct approach would be to add that directory to your library search path. You could use code like:

```
use lib 'my_modules';
use Mysql_Routines';
```

Comment: Thanks, although your first suggestion appears to be wrong. The [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) suggests `use Exporter 'import'` as a valid alternative to `require`. Your second suggestion doesn't appear to be helpful either as the naming is not confused. The package is `Mysql_Routines` and the folder containing it is `my_modules`. This is called from the above directory and so doesn't need to be added to my library.

Comment: Furthermore, I specifically don't want to have to add this to my library, as I want these packages and scripts that call them to be able to work on other machines.

Comment: Yes, I updated my post to note that `use Exporter qw(import)` works just before you added your comment.

Comment: It's the "my_modules::" in your `use my_modules::Mysql_Routines` that is causing the problem. It stops your module's `import()` function from being called successfully - and that's what sets up the short alias. If you want this to work then it need to be changed to `use Mysql_Routines`. And that means you need to add "my_modules" to your library search path somehow. You can use `use lib` or set `PERL5LIB` or use the `-I` command line option, but you'll need to do it somehow.

Comment: `use 'my_modules'` also creates the following error: `syntax error at test.pl line 7, near "use 'bespokedb'" BEGIN not safe after errors--compilation aborted`

Comment: Sorry, yes. Typo. Should be `use lib 'my_modules'`. :-/

Comment: I figured it out without having to update the library search path. Solution below. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Re "It's just non-standard.", That's not true either. It's commonly used. And for a good reason; the old interface it replaced (the only you suggested) is badly designed.

Comment: You're right. I think I must have been looking at an older version of the docs - one that didn't include the newer version. And I'd never come across it before. (/me wanders off to update several training course slides...)